# PHP Codeigniter uploads failing silently, no error log, no errors, nothing

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I've almost taken this exactly as is from the CI docs, made some minor alterations to suit my needs but overall nothing significant. The folder I am attempting to upload to exists and has `777` set to its permissions.

The controller:

```
    if($this->input->post('uploads'))
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH.'../images');
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 0;
        $config['max_width']  = 0;
        $config['max_height']  = 0;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $data['errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
        }
    }
```

The View:

```
<?php
if(isset($errors))
{
    $this->genfunc->debugArray($errors);
}
if(isset($upload_data))
{
     $this->genfunc->debugArray($upload_data, 'php');
}
?>

<div id="gallery">
    <?php if (isset($images) && count($images)):
        foreach($images as $image): ?>
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>" />
            </a>                
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; else: ?>
        <div id="blank_gallery">Please Upload an Image</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div id="upload">
    <?php
    echo form_open_multipart('upload');
    echo form_upload('userfile');
    echo form_submit('uploads', 'Upload');
    echo form_close();
    ?>      
</div>
```

The view is loaded as well, everything currently gets sent back to the same page, which is expected. But having taken from the CI example in the Docs, and going over everything I see no reason why this shouldnt be working. Hoping someone can shed some light on it, maybe I am missing something?

Comment: What is the name of your controller and corresponding function?

Comment: the controllers name is upload

Comment: And it's in your `index()` function?

Comment: aside from the code above a statement to load the view with the data being the second variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently after all this futzin around. I changed

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

to

$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($upload_config);

While I was at it I changed my `$config` to `$upload_config` and that solved it. Not sure which was the conflict either using `$config` or just something flawed in the loading mechanism when the second param is passed. Either way. Uploads work now.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you enable the debugging flag in the config file. Was facing the same issue and that got it solved. Also the directory in which the error log should be created in case of errors.

Comment: On this machine I have it set to show errors, debug, etc.. my error_log wasn't showing anything. Nor was my screen, it was for lack of better words failing very silently. I have since gotten it, not 100% sure what the problem was but changing the way the libary loads, how the config reads and minor alterations I made in my own answer. solved the problem, now I have a new interesting problem. involved in renaming the file, with the use of the file name bit

Comment: renaming the file? which file and where? I would suggest if the solution to this question was found, then answer your own question here to help others. open new question for new enquiry.

Answer (score -1):

Would initially try:

1. Create an uploads directory off of your root site directory with 777 permissions
2. update $config['upload_path'] =  './uploads/';

Comment: So your saying one directory above the public_html folder?

Comment: Suggesting to create an uploads directory at the same directory level as the ci app and system folder with initial permission listed (for testing).

Comment: well it's not currently in the application folder my images or uploads is at the same level as application and system same place I keep my assets like js CSS etc.. to go one level up would to be going into my servers user folder then one up from that would be root /home/mine/public_html/uploads

Comment: `777`? No... so give the world access to the directly and allow uploads to it? no. bad! `775` maybe...